# Does $\sum^\infty_{s=1}\delta^{s-1}\frac{1}{1 + cs}$ have a closed-form expression?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

> I'm wondering whether
> $$
> \sum^\infty_{s=1}\delta^{s-1}\frac{1}{1 + c \cdot s},
> $$
> with $\delta \in (0,1)$ and $c\ge 0$ has a closed-form expression.

While I don't know of a general closed-form I can think if a special case:

Setting $c=0$ we obtain
$$
\sum^\infty_{s=1}\delta^{s-1}=\frac{1}{1-\delta},
$$
which is the geometric series. As for the more general case $c\neq 0$ I'm not sure.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by a "closed form". According to [sage](https://sagemath.org) your sum can be written in terms of a [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function): $$\frac{\,_2F_1\left(\begin{matrix} 1,\frac{1}{c} \\ \frac{c + 1}{c} \end{matrix} \middle | \ \delta \right)}{\delta}.$$ Lots of things are known about hypergeometric functions, so this may be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: I should also mention that one of the things known about hypergeometric functions is a plethora of formulas for special cases of them. I'm far from an expert, so I'm not sure if there is such a closed form in your case, but it might be worth looking. The fact that sage didn't simplify your sum any further than this, though, leads me to suspect there isn't a nicer closed form.

Comment: @tarou2 If you find one of these answers helpful please give it an upvote and accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it. I see you have never accepted a single answer given to you in your many previous questions too. Please go back and return the favor by accepting them!

Answer (score 2):

For $|x^c|< 1$, consider the geometric series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{nc}$. Then we know
$$\frac{1}{1-x^c}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{nc}.$$
So
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^c}{1-x^c}& =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{nc+c}\\
\int\frac{x^c}{1-x^c} \, dx& =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{nc+c+1}}{1+c(n+1)}\\
\int\frac{x^c}{1-x^c} \, dx& =x^{c+1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{nc}}{1+c(n+1)}.
\end{align*}
Now let $\delta=x^c$ (with $c \neq 0$), so we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{c}\int\frac{\delta^{1/c}}{1-\delta} \, d\delta& =\delta^{\frac{c+1}{c}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\delta^{n}}{1+c(n+1)}\\
\color{red}{\frac{1}{c\delta^{\frac{c+1}{c}}}\int\frac{\delta^{1/c}}{1-\delta} \, d\delta}& =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\delta^{n}}{1+c(n+1)}.
\end{align*}
So if we can solve the integral then we can get some closed form. However solving this integral may not be that straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Picking up where @Anurag left off we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\delta^{n-1}}{1+cn}
&=\frac{1}{c\delta^{\frac{c+1}{c}}}\int\frac{\delta^{1/c}}{1-\delta} \,\mathrm d\delta\\
&=\frac{1}{c\delta^{\frac{c+1}{c}}}\int_0^\delta\frac{t^{1/c}}{1-t} \,\mathrm dt\\
&\overset{t=\delta z}{=}\frac{1}{c}\int_0^1\frac{z^{1/c}}{1-\delta z} \,\mathrm dz\\
&=\frac{1}{c}\int_0^1\frac{z^{(1+1/c)-1}(1-z)^{(2+1/c)-(1+1/c)-1}}{1-\delta z} \,\mathrm dz\\
&=\frac{1}{c(1+1/c)}(1+1/c)\int_0^1\frac{z^{(1+1/c)-1}(1-z)^{(2+1/c)-(1+1/c)-1}}{1-\delta z} \,\mathrm dz\\
&=\frac{1}{c+1}\frac{\Gamma(2+1/c)}{\Gamma(1+1/c)\Gamma(1)}\int_0^1\frac{z^{(1+1/c)-1}(1-z)^{(2+1/c)-(1+1/c)-1}}{1-\delta z} \,\mathrm dz,
\end{align*}
$$
which according to [DLMF 15.6.1](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.6.E1) equals
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\delta^{n-1}}{1+cn}=\frac{1}{c+1}{_2F_1}\left({1,1+\frac{1}{c}\atop 2+\frac{1}{c}};\delta\right),
$$
with ${_2F_1}(\cdot)$ being the (Gauss) hypergeometric function.

Note that the series representation converges for $|\delta|<1$ and $c\in\Bbb C\setminus\{-1,-2,\dots\}$, whereas the hypergeometric representation can be extended to $\delta\in\Bbb C$ via analytic continuation and thus is a more general form.

Furthermore, using [this](https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/LerchPhi/26/01/02/01/) relationship we can also express this result in terms of the Lerch Transcendent as
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\delta^{n-1}}{1+cn}=\frac{1}{c}\Phi(\delta,1,1+\tfrac{1}{c}).
$$